# Styling a page that is wider than my monitors viewport

Tags: css, frontend, psd

So my boss keeps asking me for pixel by pixel perfection when I am trying to convert PSD mockups into HTML, CSS.And I run into this subtle problem that I cant find anywhere on Google to see solution.

The width of viewport in PSD file is 1600px, but my screen is only 1336px width.

Ask : how to make it pixel by pixel perfection with this different ??

Comment: Nobody will see the website without horizontal scrolling if it's 1600px wide. You should just tell your boss that it's possible, but point out that there is no point in doing it.

Suggest a design of at most 960px wide (common arbitrary number) or suggest a responsive if not just flexible design.

Comment: @BillyBrown I think that every Full HD device and most wide monitors bigger than 21'' are 1920px wide.

Comment: @xpy That's true, I meant to say “most people”, as although many people do have 21" or larger monitors, most have laptops or smaller monitors, often up to 1440px.

Comment: The most diffused screen size nowdays is 1366x768: https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Answer (score 1):

Well, getting a bigger screen is the best solution, but if this is not an option, using developer tools in Firefox or Chrome, you have the so called **Responsive Design Mode** where you can test your page in several viewports, which of course means that you can set viewports bigger than your screen size as well.

[Responsive Design Mode in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode)

[Responsive Design Mode in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en)